# Rails caching for a forum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm trying to implement a cache in my forums, and the hard part is to kept roles & groups.

So a solution that seems to be good is to use action caching to run some `before_filter` and define the `cache_path` in a proc.

```
class Forums::TopicsController < Forums::BaseController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: :show
  before_filter :load_resources
  cache_sweeper :topic_sweeper

  caches_action :show, cache_path: proc {
    if user_signed_in?
      if @topic.user == current_user || current_user.has_role?(:moderator) || current_user.has_role?(:superadmin)
        "author_forum_topic_#{@topic.id}"
      end
    else
      forum_topic_path(@forum, @topic)
    end
  }

  def show
    @post = Fo::Post.new
  end

  def create
    # ...
  end

private

  def load_resources
    @forum = Fo::Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    @category = @forum.category
    @topic = @forum.topics.find(params[:id]) if !%w(create new).include?(action_name)

    if %w(show).include?(action_name)
      authorize! :read, @topic
      @topic.register_view_by(current_user)
    end
  end
end
```

This controller look simple, but categories/forums listing are "groups" accessible, so here I can build a sum of groups ids in the cache_path

what do you think about these caching practice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying many ways for caching my forum, I choosen using Cells https://github.com/apotonick/cells

Full page caching is too hard when adding more functionality

Cells are better way to make fragment caching and testing

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [fragment caching](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html). You may cache the whole post or just part of it. In our social app we used it to cache wall posts - the part where info about user is displayed and the post body. The part with buttons like "delete", "edit", "report" was generated on every load depending on the type of the user, e.g. the owner could delete or edit, but non-owner only report.

[Fragment caching](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html) is performed in view.

Comment: The problem I want to avoid by using action caching is the generation at every requests of helpers that can be re-used by others, like CRUD links, breadcrumb etc... Then an ajax request get additional informations like csrf-token, unreaded topics...

Comment: I suppose your main motivation of introduction of caching is speed. If caching whole action and then fetching the rest information (2 requests) is faster than fragment caching. You are on the right track. Also take additional code on the client side that you have to write into consideration.

Comment: And coupled with PJAX, this is faster than ever (and don't need to get additional ajax requests.)

The main problem now is the flash notice.
Finding the flash session in the ajax request don't work correctly with `caches_action` (work great with a `caches_pages`)